# UISearchbar at the middle of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisearchbar

I want to position my UISearchBar at the middle of the screen, but I still want it to slide to the top when user starts to edit text like it was positioned strictly under navigation bar.
Do i have to take care of its frame by myself?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Have you positioned it in the middle already? Does it stay there when editing?